# use infragistics webdropdown in js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, infragistics

I am developping an ASP.NET webform application in which I have use a webdropdown component (from infragistics). I need to disabled or enabled a specific item of the webdropdown in js. I have managed to disabled server side by setting the disabled property of an item at true.

```
<ig:WebDropDown ID="myDropDown" runat="server" Width="200px" DropDownContainerWidth="200px">                            
                    </ig:WebDropDown>

c# server side :
myDropDown.Items[0].Disabled = true;
```

The problem is that I would like to do the same in js, but I can't see how to select my dropdown in js, than iterate on it items, and disabled or enabled it.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same on the client using the following code:

```
function disableItem () {
    var dd = $find("myDropDown");
    dd.get_items().get_item(0).set_disabled(true);
}
```

Here's a [link](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/ASPNET?page=Web_Client_Side_Object_Model_CSOM_Reference_Guide.html) to the client-side object model documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. But it seems strange, that there is no equivalent to set enabled a element that was previously disabled. If I try the set_disabled(false), the element is enabled and clickable, but the style "disabled" keeps displayed on the element.

Comment: What version of the Infragistics assembly are you using?